# MySQL Query to delete rows whose timestamp is older than current timestamp

Tags: mysql, delete-row

I am looking for a query that is able to delete all rows from a table in a database where timestamp is older than the current date/time or current timestamp.

Would really appreciate some help out here urgently!

Here's the query I am using but as I thought it ain't working:

```
delete from events where timestamp<CURRENT_TIMESTAMP{);
```

Comment: DELETE FROM table_name WHERE timestamp < (NOW() - INTERVAL 20 MINUTE)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
delete from events where timestamp < NOW()
```

should be enough.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but that is not working! Its deleting all the records even though the timestamp is not older than the current time/date

Comment: by "older" you meant that timestamp is > than current time? then you have to turn the statement into timestamp > NOW()

Answer (score 32):

Um... This may seem silly, but every record in the table will be older than Now(), since Now() is calculated at the time that query is processed. If you you want to delete a record that's older than another record, then you don't want to use Now(), but the timestamp from the record you're comparing the rest to. Or, if you want to delete records that are older than a specific point in time, then you need to calculate the timestamp that you want to use to compare against. For example, to delete records older than 10 minutes, you could use this:

```
DELETE FROM events WHERE timestamp < (NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)
```

Or, for deleting records that are over a day old:

```
DELETE FROM events WHERE timestamp < (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

For specific points in time (e.g. Oct. 12th, 2012 at 4:15:00 PM GMT), there's a method to do that, but the syntax escapes me, right now. Where's my MySQL manual? :)

Comment: If you used a numeric PHP timestamp, you need this extra function  `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR);`

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE FROM events WHERE timestamp < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())
```

or if it's a standard datetime

```
DELETE FROM events WHERE timestamp < NOW()
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but that is not working! Its deleting all the records even though the timestamp is not older than the current time/date

Comment: Turn the delete into a select timestamp. Can you show a couple of the timestamp values that shouldn't be in the result set? Also do a SELECT NOW().

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate (hql) Delete records older than 7 days

I am not sure, but you can Try this:

```
    String hqlQuery = "from PasswordHistory pwh "
          + "where pwh.created_date < datediff(curdate(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)";

            List<Long> userList = (List<Long>)find(hqlQuery);
    deleteAll(userList );// from baseDao

public void deleteAll(Collection list) {
        getHibernateTemplate().deleteAll(list);
    }
```

Answer (score -4):

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE date < '2011-09-21 08:21:22';
```